# Is listing as many keywords as possible a good idea to improve SEO?

Tags: html, seo, keyword-search

I've seen some websites where the number of keywords in a single HTML meta tag was 1284 and I was wondering if this is good in terms of improving SEO. Obviously having a few keywords is good but is it always more keywords = better SEO?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @aychedee care to answer why?

Comment: Not really, your question is off topic... BUT. An abnormally high keyword density is a potential flag for spammy content. That's the term you want to search for "keyword density".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to remember is that search engines are designed to rank the best websites the highest, not to rank the website that wants to use the best SEO the highest. A website that appears **original, genuine, and a good site for users** (which is what search engines like) will do far better than a website that looks like it's trying to **deceive search engines**. Listing a lot of keywords, would look deceptive to search engines and would be frowned upon.

There is a saying in SEO, content is king. It makes a lot more sense to focus on original, authentic content that is beneficial to users rather than just overloading keywords. Search engines like those kinds of sites.

In addition, the top search engines like Google, Bing, and Yahoo do not use the meta keyword tag anymore. That tag has lost most of it's relevance to SEO.

Comment: thanks for your constructive explanation